# Items are overwritten in Task

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

We're trying to fill an Palo Alto Object Group with multiple objects.
Our current script does run through all the items in the following line:

```
     static_value: "{{ item[1].addressobjectname|join }}"
```

But only registers the last object.

For Example:
We have 3 objects in the list. So we expect to add object 1, 2, 3.
Instead the script only registers the 3 and 1 and 2 are overwritten in the process.

How should we fix this?

This is our code:

```
   - name: Create object group
     with_nested:
       - "{{ tag_firewall# }}"
       - "{{ addressobjects }}"
     panos_address_group:
       provider: "{{ palo_provider }}"
       name: "Prisma-Unsecure"
       static_value: "{{ item[1].addressobjectname|join }}"
       tag: ["ansible_test_tag"]
       device_group: "{{ item[0] }}"
       description: "Created by ansible automation"
       commit: 'no'
```

Thanks in advance!

As mentioned before we expect all items to be added to the group in stead of the last one in the list.

Comment: The parameter [static_value](https://ansible-pan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/panos_address_group_module.html) should be a list. [edit] the question and provide [mre]. In particular, you should provide the value of *addressobjects*.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without the precision asked by Vladimir in comments. Meanwhile it looks like you are creating an address group for each addressojects for each firewall definition. My guess at this stage is that the last one wins with the latest address.

Guess again: I believe you want to create one group with all adresses, something like the following (to be tested and adapted with your actual input data):

```yaml
   - name: Create object group
     loop: "{{ tag_firewall# }}"
     panos_address_group:
       provider: "{{ palo_provider }}"
       name: "Prisma-Unsecure"
       static_value: "{{ addressobjects | map(attribute='addressobjectname') }}"
       tag: ["ansible_test_tag"]
       device_group: "{{ item }}"
       description: "Created by ansible automation"
       commit: 'no'
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to remove the *join* filter. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    tag_firewall: [Prod1, Prod2]
    addressobjects:
      - addressobjectname: [Test-One, Test-Three]
      - addressobjectname: [Test-Two, Test-Four]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          panos_address_group:
            provider: Palo_provider_dict
            name: Prisma-Unsecure
            static_value: "{{ item.1.addressobjectname }}"
            tag: Ansible_test_tag
            device_group: "{{ item.0 }}"
            description: Created by Ansible automation
            commit: false
      with_nested:
        - "{{ tag_firewall }}"
        - "{{ addressobjects }}"
```

shows the iteration

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Prod1', {'addressobjectname': ['Test-One', 'Test-Three']}]) => 
  msg: |-
    panos_address_group:
      provider: Palo_provider_dict
      name: Prisma-Unsecure
      static_value: "['Test-One', 'Test-Three']"
      tag: Ansible_test_tag
      device_group: "Prod1"
      description: Created by Ansible automation
      commit: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Prod1', {'addressobjectname': ['Test-Two', 'Test-Four']}]) => 
  msg: |-
    panos_address_group:
      provider: Palo_provider_dict
      name: Prisma-Unsecure
      static_value: "['Test-Two', 'Test-Four']"
      tag: Ansible_test_tag
      device_group: "Prod1"
      description: Created by Ansible automation
      commit: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Prod2', {'addressobjectname': ['Test-One', 'Test-Three']}]) => 
  msg: |-
    panos_address_group:
      provider: Palo_provider_dict
      name: Prisma-Unsecure
      static_value: "['Test-One', 'Test-Three']"
      tag: Ansible_test_tag
      device_group: "Prod2"
      description: Created by Ansible automation
      commit: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Prod2', {'addressobjectname': ['Test-Two', 'Test-Four']}]) => 
  msg: |-
    panos_address_group:
      provider: Palo_provider_dict
      name: Prisma-Unsecure
      static_value: "['Test-Two', 'Test-Four']"
      tag: Ansible_test_tag
      device_group: "Prod2"
      description: Created by Ansible automation
      commit: false

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```